# JSON data is not printing in li using jQuery in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I want to fetch category from my JSON. Please help me as I am not able to print this in `li`. Please let me know what mistakes I am making.

```html
<ul ng-repeat="categories in category">
  <li>{{data.category}}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $.getJSON("category.json", function(data, i) {
    console.log(data[0].Category);
    //var text = data[0].Category;
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var text2 = data[i];
      console.log(text2);
      array.push[text2];
    }
    return array
  });
});
```

The parsed JSON looks like this:

```
[{
  "Category": "Beauty",
  "subcategory": [{
    "name": "Baby Care",
    "items": [{
        "name": "Soap",
        "Price": "10.00"
      },
      {
        "name": "cream",
        "price": 20.00
      },
      {
        "name": "Drug Store",
        "items": [{
          "name": "Bandage",
          "price": 5.00
        }, {
          "name": "stringe",
          "price": 6.50
        }, {
          "name": " Pain Relief",
          "price": 8.00
        }, {
          "name": "First Aid Kit",
          "price": 14.99
        }, {
          "name": "Cold Relief",
          "price": 6.50
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Health and Personal Care",
        "items": []
      }, {
        "name": "HouseHold Supplies",
        "items": [{
          "name": "Air Freshener",
          "price": 1.25
        }, {
          "name": "All Purpose Cleaner",
          "price": 2.99
        }, {
          "name": "Disinfecting Wipes",
          "price": 8.99
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Firstly please take care to format your questions. This was unreadable before I edited it. Secondly, be wary of using jQuery and Angular together. I'd suggest sticking to one only.

Comment: Ok,Rory,I will take care next time ,thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Just avoid using jQuery as much as you can, particularly when AngularJS provides equivalent functionalities, here with $http.
Beside, you don't do anything with the returned array, I suppose it should be assigned to $scope.category, but then you will have issues with digest cycle...
Note that in general, we use plural for arrays (category -> categories) and singular for the iteration item (categories -> category). That would avoid confusion to future readers (including yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Almost none of your code is correct. Firstly you are not displaying the right thing.

Change your HTML to:

```
<ul ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <li>{{category}}</li>
</ul>
```

For that you would need to populate `$scope.categories` and not `var array`. So, secondly, you need to use the right asynchronous callback: `$http.get()`

Therefore, change your JS code to:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("category.json").
  then(function(res){
    var data = res.data;
    var text2;
    $scope.categories = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      text2 = data[i].Category;
      $scope.categories.push(text2);
    }
  });
});
```

---

Here is a static example (without `$http` callback):

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var data = [{
    "Category": "Beauty",
    "subcategory": [{
      "name": "Baby Care",
      "items": [{
          "name": "Soap",
          "Price": "10.00"
        },
        {
          "name": "cream",
          "price": 20
        },
        {
          "name": "Drug Store",
          "items": [{
              "name": "Bandage",
              "price": 5
            },
            {
              "name": "stringe",
              "price": 6.5
            },
            {
              "name": " Pain Relief",
              "price": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "First Aid Kit",
              "price": 14.99
            },
            {
              "name": "Cold Relief",
              "price": 6.5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Health and Personal Care",
          "items": []
        },
        {
          "name": "HouseHold Supplies",
          "items": [{
              "name": "Air Freshener",
              "price": 1.25
            },
            {
              "name": "All Purpose Cleaner",
              "price": 2.99
            },
            {
              "name": "Disinfecting Wipes",
              "price": 8.99
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }];
  var text2;
  $scope.categories = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    text2 = data[i].Category;
    $scope.categories.push(text2);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <ul ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <li>{{category}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you need to refer to the name used in the `ng-repeat`, as such:

```
<ul ng-repeat="cat in categories">
    <li>{{cat.category}}</li>
</ul>
```

Secondly, it's recommended to not mix JQuery and AngularJS together because JQuery doesn't trigger AngularJS's $digest cycle, which can lead to unexpected hard-to-debug behaviour.

In order to fetch the JSON, use the `$http service` as such:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.categories = [];

    $http.get("category.json")
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.categories = res.data;
        });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: A big thank you ,because i am new in Angular and know very little jquery ,so i was not sure how to use.Thanks for helping me,but again i will ask you such question.Please don,t mind & keep helping me:)

Comment: i tried your code but has issue  on issue: As i have number of category,it is not printing first category suppose [0,1,2,3,4] it is printing 1,2,3,4 but not 0.

Comment: Are you 100% your JSON is valid? Please run it through a validator such as https://jsonlint.com/. I don't see why the first element would be missed.

Comment: Yes i validated JSON. It is valid.If you can give me email id i can mail you screenshot also.As i don't know where to past image on stack.Here i am pasting code from debugger:

Comment: i am pasting code from debugger:<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cat in categories" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li>  
    <li ng-repeat="cat in categories" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Pantry Items</li>   
    <li ng-repeat="cat in categories" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Perishables</li>
 
</ul>

Comment: Well done :) If your issue is resolved thanks to my comment, please mark this as the preferred answer